# How to Save Circlize Chord Diagram as a graphic object

Tags: r, chord-diagram, circlize

I created a chord diagram in R using the circlize package. I noticed that this graphic is not being saved as a ggplot object.  I am trying to make the graphic an object so I can export it to excel.  Any suggestions?

```
chordDiagram(as.data.frame(ba_delivery_flow.sas7bdat), annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks =  1,
                        direction.type = "diffHeight")
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 2, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1]+5, sector.name, facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, .5), cex = 1)
circos.axis(h = "top", labels.facing = "clockwise", labels.cex = 0.5, major.tick.percentage = 0.2, sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)

}, bg.border = NA)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R has two graphics systems, `base` and `grid`. (`grid` is what `ggplot2` and `lattice` are built on.) Your plot is built with `base`, and unfortunately `base` plots are not objects R, so you cannot assign them to a variable, and saving them is a little different.

To save the plot in a file, you open up a graphics device, like `png`, put your code to draw the plot, and then use `dev.off()` to close the device. Like this:

```
png("my_plot.png") 

## all of your plotting code

dev.off()
```

See `?png` an argument list, and a few other devices too.

---

As an aside, you can save `ggplots` this way too. If you have a plot object `p`, you can put `print(p)` in between the `png()` and the `dev.off()`. This is essentially what `ggsave` does internally.